# jQuery scope with noconflict in wordpress

Tags: javascript, scope, jquery

I'm bringing a template across from an old version of Joomla into Wordpress and got quite a few javascript files that I have to use with the main referring out to functions in the others. All of these files use jQuery left right and centre and given Wordpress uses noconflict by default I thought it would be straightforward to wrap each js file up like this:

```
(function($){
....my code...
})(jQuery);
```

The problem I get is with the scope of functions that are called across files, so for example:

### File 1

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        mainmenu();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

### File 2

```
(function($){
    function mainmenu(){
        alert("hello");
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Here is the problem I get the error "uncaught ReferenceError: mainmenu is not defined", I know it will be something simple to reference the function, but I can't see it, probably be a "Doh" moment.
Any help is most appreciated. Yes I know I could just find and replace the '$' with 'jQuery' but I just thought that there must be a way to do it?

Comment: Ya, mainmenu is not defined in the scope you are trying to use it. You could set it in same scope or use a reference variable on global scope. Anyway, the function need to be defined before you are trying to use it

Comment: The function is defined before I use it, "File 2" is called before "File 1" added to the fact that the call to mainmenu is done within domready, not bothered by any of that. It's more how would I use a reference variable on global scope as you say?

Comment: it is because the `mainmenu` is a closure function within the annonymoous function in the second file.. so it is not available in file1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because the `mainmenu` is a closure function within the anonymous function in the second file.. so it is not available in file1.

One possible solution is to make it a global function, so that it will be available in the global scope.

```
(function($){
    window.mainmenu = function (){
        alert("hello");
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: That's great apart from the fact that I have hundreds of functions, I could replace all of their declarations but I might as well just replace the $ signs with jQuery. Thanks though I will probably use this method for just now